# Subtracting an integer from nested list

Tags: python, list, nested-lists, calculation, python-3.9

•   If there is enough of that sweet to sell, the system must subtract that amount entered from the quantity [item 2] so it shows the remaining number of that sweet available in the shop)
•   If there is not enough sweets to sell (the customer want to buy more sweets than available), the system must inform the user that the transaction cannot be made. Needs to be done within a def function, can anyone help with this thanks!

```
lst_s = [
["Smarties", 5, 37], ["Cookie", 8, 80], ["Fizzies", 4, 50], ["Chocolate bar", 4, 25]
]

def update_quantity():
    name = str(input("Enter name of confectionary: "))
    price = str(input("Enter price: "))
    amount = int(input("enter quantity customer wants to buy"))

    for i in range(len(lst_s)):
        item = lst_s[i]
        iamount = item[2]
        if amount > iamount:
            print("Sorry not enough in store to sell")
        else:
            iamount = iamount - amount
            print(lst_s)
```

If I input the name as Cookie, price as 8 and quantity as 3 the desired output would be:

```
["Smarties", 5, 37], ["Cookie", 8, 77], ["Fizzies", 4, 50], ["Chocolate bar", 4, 25]
```

as the quantity of 3 has been deducted from the original Cookie quantity

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def update_quantity():
  name = str(input("Enter name of confectionary: "))
  price = str(input("Enter price: "))
  amount = int(input("enter quantity customer wants to buy"))

  for i in range(len(lst_s)):
    item = lst_s[i]
    item_name = item[0]
    iamount = item[2]
    if name != item_name:
        continue
    if amount > iamount:
        print("Sorry not enough in store to sell")
    else:
        lst_s[i][2] = iamount - amount
        print(lst_s)
```

Answer (score 0):

should be relative straightforward. You may want to use dict to store the products.

```py
lst_s = [
  ["Smarties", 5, 37],
  ["Cookie", 8, 80],
  ["Fizzies", 4, 50],
  ["Chocolate bar", 4, 25],
]

def update_quantity():
    name = str(input("Enter name of confectionary: "))
    price = str(input("Enter price: "))
    amount = int(input("enter quantity customer wants to buy"))

    for product in lst_s:
        if product[0] == name:
            if amount > product[2] :
                print("Sorry not enough in store to sell")
            else:
                product[2] = product[2] - amount
            break;
    print(lst_s)
    
update_quantity();
```